# Teen sci-fi novel about a girl who finds out teacher cloned her

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, clones

I read a book around 2000 (the book looked fairly new, but might have been a new edition) that was about a young girl who wakes up on a space ship with memories of being on Earth years before. She discovers she has been cloned by her science teacher (think her skin is now blue) from a piece of her hair, and the science teacher's consciousness has been downloaded to the ship's computer, thereby controlling it.

It was a full novel, which I found in the library in the "Teen" section. It was in English, and I think the girl's flashbacks on Earth were set in America.

Any ideas what it could be called?

Comment: Was it aimed at children, YA or adults? A short story, novella or full novel? What language/nationality was it? Was it fairly new in 2000?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Was aimed at teens as I took it from that section in library. Was a full novel in English but I think was set in America during the girl's flashbacks. Can remember the teacher used one of her hairs to clone her without her knowledge. Think it was fairly new in 2000 although could have been a new edition I read maybe?